# How to discern earth from neutral?

Tags: voltage, appliances, home-installation

I have a three cable circuit in the kitchen<sup>1</sup>, I know that one is *live*, one *neutral* and one is *ground*. However, there is no colour<sup>2</sup> matching between the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60446) and the real cables, so I can't use the usual easy way, furthermore, from my brief research on the topic I've found that:

> *"...Typically Neutral is connected to earth ground at some point, usually at the breaker box. This pretty much makes earth and neutral very close in voltage. And Hot is always 220V (or the nominal line voltage) measured with reference to Neutral (and earth for that matter)..."*

thus, a voltmeter would measure the same values between *"hot"* and *neutral* , and *"hot"* and *ground*.

How to figure out which is *ground* and which is *neutral*?

---

<sup>1. EU - Greece - 220V, 50Hz</sup>

<sup>2. Real cables colours: grey, brown, white.</sup>

Comment: You  might want to fix the complete wiring to adhere to code (unless in your country code doesn't include wire colouring). Anyways usually neutral is a bit above GND when appliances nearby are operating.

Comment: Consult a qualified electrician, since you obviously don't know what you are doing and a mistake could prove very dangerous.

Comment: @PlasmaHH It is a relatively old apartment. OK, so if I turn on an appliance nearby the neutral should change value, right?

Comment: Open up another socket or appliance and see how its wired, then copy that.

Comment: @LeonHeller You were probably right, but everything worked beautifully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have proper protection in your house, connecting a small load (e.g. a light bulb) between earth and live will trip the circuit breaker, while a load placed between live and neutral will stay powered.

If the load stays powered no matter which wire you pick, then the wiring in your apartment is really screwed, to the point your insurance company may decline your claim in case of electricity-related accident.

Comment: So, earth has lower resistance and will cause large current, right?

Comment: No, there is a special device that checks that current on live and neutral are equal -- that's why the answer is qualified with "if you have proper protection".

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: After cross checking using a light bulb I confirmed what I've already knew, additionally the power went off when I connected phase with ground, so everything seems to be in order. Thanks, for the answer!

Comment: GFCIs/RCDs have only been required to be installed relatively recently (the last 20-ish years), and it is perfectly reasonable to expect a place not to have it.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere In most of the EU it's against the code not to have these, so it's quite reasonable to expect them to be present.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, but for how long? Here in NZ, they've been mandatory in new residential construction for ~20 years, but buildings older than that are unlikely to have them unless renovated. Buildings that still comply with the old rules are usually not required to be updated until otherwise modified.

Answer (score 1):

You should not get the same volts reading between live-neutral and live-earth.

Both earth and neutral wires are connected to earth. But as you can see in the following drawing

[image: Image from electricalbaba.com]

<sup>Image from electricalbaba.com</sup>

between "ground" and "neutral tied to ground", is (usually) soil, which induces  more resistance than the "direct" metallic link between neutral and the power company.

With a voltmeter (\$\approx\$ AC)

- identify first the live cable (measure volts between A and B, B and C and A and C, when you get 0 or close to 0 Volt (say between A and B), the other cable is live (C in this example)
- then measure volts between live and A, you get \$V_A\$, and between live and B to get \$V_B\$
- the lower value of \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ tells which is earth. For instance if \$V_A = 223.7\text{V}\$ and \$V_B = 221.3\text{V}\$, earth is B.

Note that the very low current going through the voltmeter between live and earth will not trip the circuit breaker.

Of course if you get the same readings (meaning earth is directly connected to neutral, usually not the case,) that method would not work.

Answer (score 0):

After a brief experimentation with the voltmeter, three measurements are needed to determine ground, neutral and phase:

1. Voltage between phase and any of the other two should be around 220V.
2. Voltage between neutral and ground should be 0V. (determine phase)

    <strike>3. After shutting down supply, the lowest Resistance between phase and the rest of the two determines the ground.</strike> 

   3. Connect a heavy load to generate enough voltage drop and determine the neutral, which will be less. In other words, when you plug in another device the voltage between phase and neutral will be less than the voltage if the same device is not plugged.

Following the above, in my case, grey = neutral, brown = phase, white (yellowish (old)) = ground.

Comment: Not sure whether your method actually works. When you shut down the power, both live and neutral must be cut off, so the resistance between both of them and ground should be "infinite".

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You are right, it shows 1.

Comment: This is not a definitive test, be careful.  If you do as suggested in a comment above and load a different KNOWN GOOD socket and then measure voltages between the live (found using test 1 or 2)  and the two others you should see slight reduction of voltage between live and neutral and less reduction between live and earth.  The difference may be slight enough that it could be misinterpreted.  If the RCCI test works that will be much safer.  Local reputable electrician will know what to do.